# Position Keyboard Caret Between Two Html Tags

Tags: javascript, angular, caret

I have the following html

```
<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, <mark>sed do eiusmod</mark></span>
```

and I'm trying to position the caret between the `</mark> | </span>` tags.

I've used the following code and it works if the last Node is text and not mark, but when its mark tag it just position the caret at the end of the mark tag.

```
const range = document.createRange();
      let deepLastChildNode = this.elementRef.nativeElement.childNodes[this.elementRef.nativeElement.childNodes.length - 1];

      const sel = window.getSelection();
      range.setStart(deepLastChildNode, deepLastChildNode.length || 1);
      range.collapse(true);

      sel.removeAllRanges();
      sel.addRange(range);
```

the nativeElement is and angular 5 reference to the DOM HTMLElement.

Comment: you could use innerHtml https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML   you want to target the span and get its html contents and then you can position the caret anywhere as it is returned as a string.

Comment: @floor can you provide a code as an example? because the range.setStart only takes nodes and an offset. I dont see where the innerHTML can help me here.

Comment: Its hard for the to create an example using your code. I could only guess, but this.elementRef.nativeElement likely has .innerHTML property. So try something like let testElement = this.elementRef.nativeElement; then next line do console.log(testElement.innerHTML) and put a break point on that console log line to see what methods and properties you have access to on nativeElement. Is there a specific reason you are using range?

Comment: because only with range I can position the keyboard Caret in a specific place.

Comment: ohhh I misunderstood the questions I thought you wanted to add the ^ character between tags.